# Ruby on Rails display hours calculated from two datetime fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table that contains `starts_at:datetime` and `ends_at:datetime`.

In the index view, I would like to display the hours between the two datetime fields.

How would I do that?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: can you post an example of the outpout you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the format you expect. You can use [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) for example

If you need the number of hours between the 2 dates:

```
((foo.ends_at - foo.stars_at) / 1.hour).to_i
```

Comment: This won't display the calculated fields: `<% if event.all_day == true %>
        <td><%= event.hours %></td>
    <% else %>
        <td><% ((event.ends_at - event.starts_at) / 1.hour).to_i %></td>
    <% end %>`

Comment: The hours display for the all_day events, but not the calculated ones.

Comment: My fault - forgot the = after <%